# A Rule of Divisibility by 7 - Codewars Javascript Challenge

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

For this [codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/a-rule-of-divisibility-by-7/train/javascript)

The following code passes tests but it's experiencing a timeout error:

```js
function seven(m) {
 let count = 0;
 m = String(m);
 while (Number(m.slice(0, m.length - 1)) - (Number(m[m.length - 1]) * 2) % 7 !== 0) {
  let first = Number(m.slice(0, m.length - 1));
  let second = Number(m[m.length - 1]) * 2;
  m = first - second;
  count++;
  m = String(m);
 }
 return [Number(m), count];
}

console.log(seven(483));
```

As I understand, the idea is to continue breaking a number down until it's divisible by 7. Stop when the number has *at most* 2 digits.

> A number m of the form 10x + y is divisible by 7 if and only if x − 2y is divisible by 7. In other words, subtract twice the last digit from the number formed by the remaining digits. Continue to do this until a number known to be divisible or not by 7 is obtained; you can stop when this number has at most 2 digits because you are supposed to know if a number of at most 2 digits is divisible by 7 or not.
>
> The original number is divisible by 7 if and only if the last number obtained using this procedure is divisible by 7.

**Example**:

`1 - m = 371 -> 37 − (2×1) -> 37 − 2 = 35 ;`

thus, since 35 is divisible by 7, 371 is divisible by 7.

And I'm not sure how else to optimize this code. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question and that's why my while-loop is overly complicated. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** - second attempt - trying to avoid converting to String and back to Number:

```js
function seven (m) {
 let count = 0;
 while ((String(m).length > 2) && (m % 7 !== 0)) { 
  let last = (m % 10);
  let first = (m - last) / 10;
  m = (first - (last * 2));
  count++;
 }
 return [m, count];
}
```

This is passing 84 tests, failing 26.

Comment: Converting back and forth between numbers and strings may be the problem. You can get the last digit of a number with `last_digit = m % 10`, and the preceding digits with `(m - last_digit) / 10`.

Comment: Your loop only stops when the number is found to be divisible by 7. It doesn't stop when you get to a 2-digit number that isn't divisible by 7.

Comment: @Barmar Please see my updated attempt. I've eliminated converting to String and Back to Number, but something is still wrong.

Comment: `String(m).length > 2` is equivalent to m > 99, except with the latter being more efficient

Comment: The instructions don't say to stop when the number is divisible by 7.

Comment: It seems like you misread the instructions. You're not required to determine if the number is divisible by 7, just perform the repeated additions of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compute the `input` until it is smaller than 3 digits and return the count.

Please try this:

```
function seven(m) {    
  let count = 0;

  while(m > 99) {
    m = parseInt(m / 10) - (2 * (m % 10)); 
    count++;
  }

  return [m, count];
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the instructions say to return: **Your task is to return ... an array ... of numbers, the first being the last number m with at most 2 digits obtained by your function (this last m will be divisible or not by 7), the second one being the number of steps to get the result.**

Comment: Ah, thx I haven't noticed that < divisible or not by 7> then my solution is good :)